# How do I minimize the total distance traveled in moving goods between warehouses?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures

There are N warehouses storing Q[i] quantity of an item on Day 1. On day 2, the requirements are for quantity Q'[i] in each warehouse. So basically item has to be moved between warehouses to fulfill the constraint. The distance between warehouses is known. What class of algorithms can solve this? Any pointers? The goal is to minimize the distance traveled in moving goods.

Comment: Sounds kind of similar to the traveling salesman problem

Comment: NOTE: the OP has not said that a single path/truck must connect/travel to all of the warehouses.  If *not* then this problem is NOT like the travelling salesman problem.

Comment: You are right, my fingers went too fast for my brain to follow along. I have deleted my answer which relates it to the TSP.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem which is solved with a min-cost max-flow algorithm. You augment your graph by adding two extra vertices: a source and a sink. From the source to all vertices of the original graph you add an edge with capacity equal to `Q[i]` and zero cost. From each vertex of the original graph you add an edge to the sink with capacity equal to `Q'[i]` and zero cost. For the edges between the vertices of the original graph you set the capacity to infinity and cost to the distance between the corresponding warehouses, and then compute the min-cost max-flow. The flow between the vertices of the original graph will tell you how many goods to transfer between those two warehouses.

Some links:

1. [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) about min-cost max-flow
2. A very good [presentation](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-082j-network-optimization-fall-2010/lecture-notes/MIT15_082JF10_lec13.pdf) (they have a problem similar to yours there but not identical)
3. Here's a [great article](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/minimum-cost-flow-part-one-key-concepts/) with the details of a very good implementation